# Installing Elastic search with Ubuntu windows

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, ubuntu-18.04

would really appreciate any input.

I've been trying to learn elastic search with a tutor.

He's a Mac user, thus the process was a complete nightmare

we just can't install it with Ubuntu.

I can't install it on my Machine, he tried as well on his and same thing.

Anyone has any inputs/ experience with this.

It was a painful process...........

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest the following:

- install Docker on Windows: [link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/)
- clone or download this repository: [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)

Now you just need to:

- do the following to avoid future hassle: [link](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk#how-to-disable-paid-features)
- run Docker
- open your favorite terminal
- run `docker compose up` in the `docker-elk` folder

You will get a running instance of Elasticsearch, a running instance of Logstash, and a running instance of Kibana.